# If-else under switch case in shell scripting

Tags: shell, if-statement, resolve

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Enter choice :
echo a : To create a file, name given by user.
echo b : To copy file to another location.
echo c : To determine minimum age to vote.

read choice
case $choice in

    a) echo Enter the name of file.
        read name
        mkdir $name ;;
    b) echo Enter file name you want to copy
        read  file_name
      echo Enter location where you want to copy $file_name
        read location
        cp -r  $file_name "$location";;
    c) echo Enter age :
        read age
        if [ age -ge 18 ]
        then 
        echo You are eligible 
        else 
        echo You are not eligible
        "fi" 
        ;;
        
    *) echo Please! Enter correct choice.
 
esac
```

in this I am choosing option c but it is showing the error which i cannot able to solve.

Error :

```
Enter choice :
a : To create a file, name given by user.
b : To copy file to another location.
c : To determine minimum age to vote.
c
./a.sh: 27: Syntax error: ";;" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Comment: Do you really have `"fi"` in quotes?

Comment: remove the dbl-quotes from `"fi"` and you should be good. But learn to check your first check your code at https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Help to fix your code,  you can compare your code as a reference

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo Enter choice :
echo a : To create a file, name given by user.
echo b : To copy file to another location.
echo c : To determine minimum age to vote.

read -r choice
case $choice in

    a) echo Enter the name of file.
        read -r name
        mkdir "$name" ;;
    b) echo Enter file name you want to copy
        read -r file_name
      echo Enter location where you want to copy "$file_name"
        read -r location
        cp -r  "$file_name"  "$location";;
    c) echo Enter age :
        read -r age
        if [ "$age" -ge 18 ]
        then 
        echo You are eligible 
        else 
        echo You are not eligible
        fi
        ;;
        
    *) echo Please! Enter correct choice.
 
esac
```

Comment: Why you are using -r

Comment: read without -r will mangle backslashes.